# Import PHP Variables in a pop up window

Tags: php

I have an original php page and a popup window written in php, I wonder how to import the variables in the original page into the popup window. One possible problem is the variable in the original page is not defined in itself but in other php pages connected to it, and it will change based on user's choice. Sincerely looking forward to suggestions, thanks!

It is like:
Two files "business.php" and "school.php" share a header file called "info.php", in "business.php" $theme = "business"; and in "school.php" $theme = "school".
In header file, I can use

```
if($theme=="business"){
  echo "<a href='#' onclick='popitup();'>Popup</a>";
}
```

to have a button in the business header part.
The function for the popup window is like:

```
function popitup() {
  var newWindow = window.open('/../popitup.php', 'name');

  if (window.focus) {
      newwindow.focus()
  }
  return false;
}
```

What I hope to have is using the $theme variable in "popitup.php", such as when user click the "Popup" link from business page, the popup page can show a list of options related to business information.

Comment: You probably want session variables. Look them up.

Comment: Popup window appears on client side, php works server side. So, your popup window __is not__ written in php. Second, read [tour] and __especially__ [mcve].

Comment: Hi  Nan, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Would you please go into more detail? Perhaps some code? Are you using Post or Get to pass variables? Or sessions? Or classes?

Comment: It is not possible to write popup window in PHP. It is only written in JavaScript.

Comment: @SaidbakR that is not entirely true.  You can use the `target='_new'` attribute and open a window from an `anchor` tag making it a popup.  --straight html, no javascript.

Comment: @RobertDickey Sorry I cannot share any code here coz it is a private project I do for a company. The php variable I would like to import is defined by POST in many pages to distinguish them. Like $theme is defined as "business" in one page while as "school" in another, user could choose to look business info by  choosing a button on their shared header part.

Comment: @NanDeng if no code, an example would help those trying to help you to understand what you are going for.  Failing that, just some ideas on what you have tried is often appreciated.  The community seems to help those that help themselves.  Specifics are not as important as a conceptual idea of what you are looking for.

Comment: @NappingRabbit It may be wrong but not entirly wrong, the common and popular mean of popup is creating new **controlled** client window. For that mean, Javascript is regarded as the main way and some CSS may be used to improve the UI.

Comment: @SaidbakR I agree, and I will admit I was splitting hairs.  You can however style the `_new` window in such a way that it behaves similarly for those without JS turned on.

Comment: what's the status of this question? There's an answer below. If it did solve it, it should be accepted in order to mark it as solved. If it didn't, a comment should be placed under it stating so. If the question was solved already, it needs an answer or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like the following:

first, start a session and maintain that for all of your pages.

The page that calls the `main` page sounds like the best place to centralize these things.  Let's call that your `controller` although it may be a misnomer depending on your setup.  However, if it is where the variables you are talking about are defined, it is likely close enough. 
 Have it call your `popup`, being practically persistent now.  Problem solved.

You may want to look into Model-View-Controller (MVC) as well as Object Oriented Programming (OOP) concepts.  Make no mistake, this is not that, but a good architecture with planning can make things much easier.

TLDR: **sessions**

here is a [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

here is a [user friendly link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

**edit:** just incase you do not want to refactor something you have already in place, you can call your `popup` with a `query string` at the end of your url and access them with `$_GET[]` on the php side.  [Here is a link](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) for that.  Then it would be something like, `page.php?option1=abcd&option2=efgh` I think of that as messy and a bit antiquated, but it is valid and works fine.

**another edit:** another option is using `cookies` that you store in the user's client.  It is not as fool-proof though because people may not have them on, but it may accomplish what you are looking for.  [Here is a link](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) for those.

**third edit:** you can store your user's choices in a database and pull them with code in the popup as it is rendered.